# Toggle height of Div Size

Tags: jquery

I am searching for a simple way to expand a div to a fixed height.
This would be the basic skeleton of my code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <a class="more" href="#">More</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

With click on "more", I want the parent div to expand to a height of 400px. With clicking "more" (better would be "less") again, I want the parent div to resize back to it's former height (200px).

Somehow nothing I found on the internet worked. And since I am an absolute greenhorn with jQuery I can't find the mistake... I assume a problem might be the lack of proper element identification since each class is used several times on the website...

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEuXG/1/)

html:

```
   <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <a class="more" href="#">More</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

js

```
    var div = $("div.parent");
$("a.more").click(function(){
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() == "more"){
        div.animate({height:400}, 500);
        $(this).text("Less");   
    }            
    else{
       div.animate({height:200}, 500);
         $(this).text("More");   
    }

});
```

Comment: I am sorry for bothering you again:
Is there a way of restricting the changes made by jQuery to the respective div? When I have several divs with the class "parent", changes will be made to each of them. But I need just the respective div to change...

Comment: Oh, I just sent the comment too early. I am not used to the automatic posting of comments by pressing return. Please see the edit of my previous post.

Comment: those div need to have some specific identification eg. special id. so that you can filter them while running jQuery selector.

Answer (score 0):

With the edition of some CSS:

```
.parent.large {
    height: 400px;
}
```

You can use the following JavaScript:

```
var $parent = $('.parent');

var $link = $('.more').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($parent.hasClass('large')) {
        $parent.removeClass('large');
        $link.text('More');
    } else {
        $parent.addClass('large');
        $link.text('Less');
    }
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LepHL/) of it in action.

Answer (score 0):

I added a less element to your HTML so that the parent may be collapsed after it is expanded.

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="bar">
        <a class="more" href="#">More</a>
        <a class="less" href="#">Less</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.less{
    display: none;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var originalHeight = $(".parent").height();
$(".more").click(function(e){
   toggle(this,400, ".less");
   e.preventDefault();
});

$(".less").click(function(e){
   toggle(this,originalHeight, ".more");
   e.preventDefault();
});

function toggle(element, height, toggleClass){
   $(element).parents(".parent").animate({"height":height + "px"},1000);
   $(element).hide();
   $(toggleClass).show();
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/bsF6V/1/